# I have an issue when zooming in on a fractal (webgl)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, fragment-shader

When I zoom in too much and I drag the picture using my mouse it just moves too fast. Similarly if I zoom out too much the picture drags very slowly.

This is how it is zooming in (scale) and how it drags the picture around (xPos, yPos)

```
fPosition.x = fPosition.x * scale + xPos;
fPosition.y = fPosition.y * scale + yPos;
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the movement by the inverse scale. When at 1 to 1 no zoom you move the image 1 pixel for every one pixel you drag.

When you are zoomed in at 2 to 1. One pixel is now 2 pixels wide (you have a scale of 2) you still want to drag the image at the same screen speed so you move it `1/scale` pixels for every pixel you drag. `1/2 = 0.5` for every one pixel you move your mouse/pointer/touch thing .

When zoomed out 0.5 to 1, the scale is now 0.5 and the images is half its size you need to move it `1/scale` pixels for every pixel you drag. `1/0.5 = 2`

So scale is how big a pixel is and movement is the inverse of that scale. 1 divide scale

Comment: fPosition.x = fPosition.x * scale + xPos*(1/scale);

Comment: If I did it like the above it would actually change the position when zooming in/out.

Comment: @Besta only keep one position coordinate, not 2 and add to that. (In shader) `fPosition  = pos * scale;` and when you move (in Javascript)`pos += drag * (1/scale);`